# Better cross platform development tool for iOS compatibility than Xamarin?

Tags: android, ios, c#, cross-platform

I need to create an app which will be published on Google Play and the App Store. Having already made cross platform apps a few years ago with Xamarin, with most of the code shared in both platforms, I faced a few difficulties which I would like to avoid.

The app to make is pretty simple, a shopping app. Tabs, categories, lists of products and descriptions, basket, payment integrated to the app, notifications. But I'm mostly afraid of the UI part.

At that time I was using VS 2017, now I see there is a 2019. Maybe the issues I had have been solved with the update?

- iOS UI compatibility, only to give an example: I was using **ListView** to display a list of elements with variable height. On Android the result was always fine, but completely messed up on iOS.
- iOS export issues. Not having a Mac I can't properly test and build the app to be published in App Store.
- Performance. Of course cross developed apps aren't as fast as native ones, but it's still a requirement to find the best alternative.

So did Xamarin improve this points since the 2017 version? Or should I look somewhere else>

In my researches I found good alternatives in Flutter and React Native, but it will imply learning a new language plus using a new IDE. Being pretty familiar with VS and C# now, it would take good arguments to make me change.

Comment: [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bnYJRYFsrSw) is quite long but really gives full-length, up-to-date infos about a large array of dev paradigm. It doesn't focus on Xamarin, but I'd highly recommend it to someone asking themself *what should I learn next in mobile dev?*